# messageFormt() Error with multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, messageformat

Hello I am trying to run my program but I am getting a really weird output. This program works when its a single array but when I make it a multidimensional it errors out. please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat("insert into {0} values ( ''{1}'', ''{2}'', ''{3}'', ''{4}'' )");
            Object[][] data = { {"000", "111", "222","333","444","555"},
                               {"000", "123", "234","345","456","567"} }; 

            System.out.println(messageFormat.format(data));
}
```

my output is:

```
run:
insert into [Ljava.lang.Object;@2a134eca values ( '[Ljava.lang.Object;@52934c3b', '{2}', '{3}', {4} )
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageFormat` with the format provided is perfect for printing 1-D array. Yet it cannot print 2-D array out of the box.

You need to iterate over your 2-D array `data`:

```
for(Object[] array : data) {
    System.out.println(messageFormat.format(array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `data` in, you are passing in an array of objects (which also happen to be arrays of Objects). So the first one is `data[0]` and the second one is `data[1]`, both of which appear to be `Object[]` of size 6.

To fix this:

```
 messageFormat.format(data[0]);
```

A word of caution, it seems that you may be using this for a SQL insert statement. I'd strongly advise you to use a `PreparedStatement` instead, as this method is error prone and leads to SQL injection attacks if you aren't very careful!

Comment: -Todd thank you for your help, I will take a look into PreparedStatement